# Android - Add Lines to Textview

Tags: android, line

Ive got a TextView and some String Arrays. I want to add a Line (trough Java) everytime the next Item is displayed(Ive got a for loop, so it loops until every Item is displayed in the TextView). Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you

EDIT:
I want It to look like a ListView. But I dont want to use a listView insted because I want to set the Line just for certain events.

Comment: You can use a listView and an Adapter Textview class to inflate what ever you want.
And you can also create a custom textview and draw a line at the bottom the add this text view with an Array Adapter to the List view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++)
{
    //textview is tv
   tv.setText(listOfString[i]);
   //view is viewWithHorizontalLine with hight = dp and width = fill_parent and background = #000000
   viewWithHorizontalLine = view;
   //LinearLayout is ll
   ll.addView(tv);
   ll.addView(viewWithHorizontalLine);
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView>
      <LinearLayout orientation=vertical/>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of line?  If you just want a vertical line in your text, add "|" between each word.  If you want a new line, use "\n".

Comment: Didn't think of that, but yes, what kind of line is a very good question!

Comment: a horizontal line.... so simply it looks like a listview. But I dont want a ListView

Comment: You can't really do that.  Your best bet would be to either a) switch to a ListView, or b) (and this is a horrible idea) use a line of "\_"s to create a line, resulting in something like this: "___________________________________________________________________"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a newline (`\n`) character each time you add one of your strings?

Comment: a horizontal line.... so simply it looks like a listview. But I dont want a ListView